# CloudWatch alarm based on time-based MathExpression

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to use the following `MathExpression` to create a CloudWatch alarm based on (expression is somewhat simplified):

`IF(6 >= HOUR(TIME_SERIES(1)) && HOUR(TIME_SERIES(1)) <= 23, 1, 0)`

In the AWS console, I can add this expression and see how the metric emits 1 during the night and 0 during the day (06:00 - 23:00), so this part seems to work.

However, when I try to create an alarm based on the above expression, the following error is shown: "Error in expression 'expr_1': No valid period found for HOUR() function."

Is there any way in which I can create an alarm based on the expression? The alarm should trigger if the metric is below 1 for 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the following expression: "IF(HOUR(count) > 6 AND HOUR(count) < 23, count)"

Where count is a metric of CloudWatch (API Gateway).

I then created an alarm, which ignores missing data and thus maintains there current alarm state.

My CDK code (Java) looks as following:

```
MathExpression metricCountCorrected = new MathExpression(MathExpressionProps.builder()
        .expression("IF(HOUR(count) > 6 AND HOUR(count) < 23, count)")
        .usingMetrics(Map.of("count", restApi.metric("Count", MetricOptions.builder()
                .statistic(Stats.SUM)
                .period(Duration.minutes(5))
                .build())))
        .period(Duration.minutes(5))
        .build());

 metricCountCorrected.createAlarm(this, prefix.asIs() + "x", CreateAlarmOptions.builder()
        .alarmName(prefix.asIs() + "x")
        .treatMissingData(TreatMissingData.IGNORE)
        .comparisonOperator(ComparisonOperator.LESS_THAN_THRESHOLD)
        .evaluationPeriods(1)
        .threshold(1)
        .build());
```